# If you are very bad administrator and don't like administration but want to create a web app, would you consider "on the cloud" offers?

Tags: cloud

For example, I'm going to create a startup but me and my co-founder are bad administrators and good .NET developers and we just want to code cool and useful web applications. Should we consider using Azure for this reason ? (We really think that writing code will generate more money and fun than trying to learn and administrate a server ourselves, because we are not good for that)

My question is not Microsoft centric, you can replace Azure and .NET by Python and Google App Engine if you want.

Answer (score 1):

First try to create something people will like and will be using.

If you succeed you will then think of administration issues. Maybe you will even have enough money to get a profi to undertake this work.

Comment: My question is not about how to create a web application in a startup,  I'm more interested to know if you think that my reason for using Azure ou on the cloud solution, is valid.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Whether it's a cloud or conventional hosting, there will be support team watching the system 24/7.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, write your app on a simple FTP, using a simple http server, then think about it.

And if you really need what you're asking, then it belong to the core of your project, so you **need** to learn it.

Comment: The core of the project is software, we don't want it to be IT. To your mind, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using a service to host your app, hence freeing you from admin chores is reasonable. You sacrifice control, but reduce hassle.

A couple of things to consider:

1. Does using such cloud computing regimes tie your software to that infrastructure. Should you be sufficiently successful so that you want to bring the admin in-house or to a different provider are you in for major rewrite?
2. What QOS can you count on? What do they promise? Have they delivered?

Comment: I admit that the site web will be very small, (between 1-50 users depending how we're doing well), so the QOS we need is very small. Currently I know nothing about Azure, and I agree with you that I should evaluate if it will tie my software to their infrastructure.